# Windows Forms compatibility in Windows 8.1 - Windows 10

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-10, compatibility

The Windows Forms code generated by Visual Studio when modified by the designer is not the same if I develop of Windows 8.1 than if I develop in Windows 10. This will result in all my sizes to be increased by a factor close to 1.5 (from Windows 8 to Windows 10).

This might look like an autoscale in order to fit the screen resolution. The problem is that a lot of my code depends heavily on the size and thus the impact is way more than just a "resize" of my whole screen. The generated code also add some margin and padding.

Is there a way to disable all these OS related changes when I modify the code?

Comment: Is the DPI setting in your Windows 10 150%? (Right click on Desktop/Screen resolution/Make text and other items larger or smaller)

Comment: Thanks you so much. I never expected a user setting of the display could affect the code generator.